# Special char issue

Tags: json, api, asp.net-core

I'm creating an .Net Core API but I have a problem I wanted to keep the '$' special char in the password.

I don't know why, when I execute my post method in the request URL it change it to %24

I try to change use Normalize but it didn't work...

Authentication Controller which is called by Employee controller :

```
public static class AuthenticationController
{
    private class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        private SafeTokenHandle() // called by P/Invoke
            : base(true)
        {
        }

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return CloseHandle(this.handle);
        }
    }

    private enum LogonType : uint
    {
        Network = 3, // LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK
    }

    private enum LogonProvider : uint
    {
        WinNT50 = 3, // LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(
        string userName, string domain, string password,
        LogonType logonType, LogonProvider logonProvider,
        out SafeTokenHandle token);

    public static void AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password)
    {

        string domain = "domain";
        string parts = domain + userName;

        SafeTokenHandle token;
        if (LogonUser(userName, domain, password, LogonType.Network, LogonProvider.WinNT50, out token))
            token.Dispose();
        else
            throw new Win32Exception(); // calls Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    }
}
```

Employee controller :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    private readonly intranetApplicationAPIContext _context;

    public EmployeeController(intranetApplicationAPIContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetEmployee(string username , string password)
    {
        try
        {

            AuthenticationController.AuthenticateUser(username, password);

            return Ok(username +"-"+ password);
        }
        catch (Win32Exception ex)
        {
            switch (ex.NativeErrorCode)
            {
                case 1326: // ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE (incorrect user name or password)
                    return BadRequest("Error code : "+ex.NativeErrorCode+" Incorrect username or password");

                case 1327: // ERROR_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION
                    return BadRequest("Error code : " + ex.NativeErrorCode + " Account restriction");

                case 1330: // ERROR_PASSWORD_EXPIRED
                    return BadRequest("Error code : " + ex.NativeErrorCode + " Password expired");

                case 1331: // ERROR_ACCOUNT_DISABLED
                    return BadRequest("Error code : " + ex.NativeErrorCode + " Account disabled");

                case 1907: // ERROR_PASSWORD_MUST_CHANGE
                    return BadRequest("Error code : " + ex.NativeErrorCode + " Password must change");

                case 1909: // ERROR_ACCOUNT_LOCKED_OUT
                    return BadRequest("Error code : " + ex.NativeErrorCode + " Account locked out");

                default: // Other
                    return BadRequest("An error has occured");
                    ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you **execute post method**? What is your `Core API`? `AuthenticateUser` seems to be a method instead of `Controll API`. I could not reproduce your issue by Controller API like `        [HttpPost("/AuthenticateUser")]
        public void AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password)
`. Share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: I use Angular and I don't know yet how to get response body and I think my post method is false but I don't know where and why but thank you for your help

Comment: Share us the code related with sending request from Angular, you may try `Postman` to send request to check whether api is working. Maybe you could share us a simple demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: I ask an other question if you want to see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837770/issue-error-204-and-400

And for postman I don't know why but it send me that it "could not get any response" cause there was error connecting to the api url

Comment: Share us your Controller api and Postman screenshot.

Comment: I edit my code and here it's my picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKkFL.png

Comment: check turn off 'ssl certificate verification' in Settings->General in postman. When sending request from angular, will you get right value for `password` in `GetEmployee(string username , string password)`?

Comment: Normally it should send the right value in my login.component.ts ( stackoverflow.com/questions/51837770/issue-error-204-and-400) onSubmit the 2 parameters where good.

Comment: So do you get right value when you debug web api?

Comment: I have the right value but I don't understand why even if the result is true or false in angular it send me the same message with the user information

Comment: Could not understand what your issue is? Is your issue that web api return wrong result, or angular could not deserialize response? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: You can see all my authentication in Angular there :  stackoverflow.com/questions/51837770/issue-error-204-and-400

I don't know when I use post method for the API on postman it's work but when I want to do something in the angular I have errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending password or user private information in url is not recommmended.(Someone who listen the network can see request url and steal user password) You can send these informations in body of post request to dont encounter encoding problem and realizing process securely

Comment: Thank you for your help I see It on my response body